# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1

Tags: c#, sql, linq

When I execute the following code:

```
IHotelDataAccess _hotelDataAccess= new HotelDataAccess(_entities);
int myVal = (from u in _hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(19)
    select u).Count();
```

myVal returns an integer value as expected, however if I try and return the IQueryable as below

```
return (from geoLocation in _entities.ViewGeographyLocation
 where geoLocation.CountryCode == countryCode
 orderby geoLocation.SortOrder, geoLocation.CityName
 select new ContinentModel
 {
  ContinentCode = geoLocation.ContinentCode,
  ContinentName = geoLocation.ContinentName,
  CountryCode = geoLocation.CountryCode,
  CountryName = geoLocation.CountryName,
  CityId = geoLocation.CityId,
  CityName = geoLocation.CityName,
  CityCode = geoLocation.CityName,
  TotalCount = ((from u in _hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(19)
   select u).Count())
 });
```

I get the error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DestKosher.Model.HotelModel]
>   GetHotelsByCityId(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

The method hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(19) return IQueryable.  Any thoughts, help or solutions would be most appreciated.  Regards,

Martin

## **UPDATE:**

This query was initially setup to see if by putting an integer into the function GetHotelsByCityId would work.  However, what I want to do ultimately is:

```
return (from geoLocation in _entities.ViewGeographyLocation
 where geoLocation.CountryCode == countryCode
 orderby geoLocation.SortOrder, geoLocation.CityName
 select new ContinentModel
 {
  ContinentCode = geoLocation.ContinentCode,
  ContinentName = geoLocation.ContinentName,
  CountryCode = geoLocation.CountryCode,
  CountryName = geoLocation.CountryName,
  CityId = geoLocation.CityId,
  CityName = geoLocation.CityName,
  CityCode = geoLocation.CityName,
  TotalCount = ((from u in _hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(geoLocation.CityId)
   select u).Count())
 });
```

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you...

Comment: Can you have a look at my update. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

By design, *[LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx)* requires the whole LINQ query expression to be translated to a server query. Only a few uncorrelated subexpressions (expressions in the query that do not depend on the results from the server) are evaluated on the client before the query is translated. Arbitrary method invocations that do not have a known translation, like GetHotelsByCityId() in this case, are not supported.

you can do like this

```
var list = _hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(19).ToList();
int myVal = (from u in list
    select u).Count();
```

than us myval in your query

```
return (from geoLocation in _entities.ViewGeographyLocation
 where geoLocation.CountryCode == countryCode
 orderby geoLocation.SortOrder, geoLocation.CityName
 select new ContinentModel
 {
  ContinentCode = geoLocation.ContinentCode,
  ContinentName = geoLocation.ContinentName,
  CountryCode = geoLocation.CountryCode,
  CountryName = geoLocation.CountryName,
  CityId = geoLocation.CityId,
  CityName = geoLocation.CityName,
  CityCode = geoLocation.CityName,
  TotalCount = myVal 
 });
```

Read in more Deatil : [LINQ to Entities, what is not supported?](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/LINQ-to-Entities-what-is-not-supported.aspx)

Comment: This is what I want:'return (from geoLocation in _entities.ViewGeographyLocation
 where geoLocation.CountryCode == countryCode
 orderby geoLocation.SortOrder, geoLocation.CityName
 select new ContinentModel
 {
  ContinentCode = geoLocation.ContinentCode,
  ContinentName = geoLocation.ContinentName,
  CountryCode = geoLocation.CountryCode,
  CountryName = geoLocation.CountryName,
  CityId = geoLocation.CityId,
  CityName = geoLocation.CityName,
  CityCode = geoLocation.CityName,
  TotalCount = (from u in _hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(geoLocation.CityId).ToList()
    select u).Count(); });'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the namespace "System.Linq" and also check your project references if you have "System.Core" assembly reference.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the above update.  Many thanks, Martin

Comment: can you post your code for _hotelDataAccess.GetHotelsByCityId(19), so we can disect deeper.